# window.close() from backing bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to close the main window if a certain condition satisfies. If it does not satisfy, then it should show a dialog box. I am able to show the dialog box when the condition does not satisfy, but i am not able to close the window when it does. What function can I call to close the window? is the approach used for closing the window correct?

```
if(condition() == false){

   context.execute("PF('dialogbox').show();");
}else{

   context.execute("PF(window.close());"); //

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I'm 1000% sure you have javascript errors in the browser developer console when using

```
context.execute("PF(window.close());"); //
```

The solution is to use

```
context.execute("window.close();"); //
```

But most likely you'll get a warning in the browser since closing from an ajax response is considered not common practice and often used by spam sites

Comment: Thanks!!! can you suggest an alternate and safer way of closing the window

Comment: Define 'safer'.... It **is** safe, just (most likely, I'm not 100% sure) will give the user a warning

Comment: Did you use this? It is **the** answer.